# What are the disadvantages of discarding symbols?

Tags: c, gnu, strip

the program `strip` on GNU/Linux ([man](http://linux.die.net/man/1/strip)) allows you to discard symbols from object files or executables. By doing this you gain a smaller file size.

So my question is what are the trade-offs of discarding the symbols?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It makes debugging a great deal harder, since you no longer know what variables or functions are stored where in memory.

Comment: Post-mortem core dump analysis is harder if you don't have the symbols in the executable.

Comment: So if I don't want to analyse core dumps or debug the executable, I can simply discard the symbols and save space?

Comment: You can always recompile a new copy of the binary with exactly the same libraries and settings, and use that to debug the core or even a live executable. I did this once when my `screen` session hung with unsaved critical data in it - I built an identical screen binary and used it to attach the running process in gdb and change the value of a variable that had it stuck in an infinite loop.

Comment: @R, if I'm not mistaken, tools like the [DrKonqui](http://techbase.kde.org/Development/Tutorials/Debugging/How_to_create_useful_crash_reports) also rely on that technique (same libraries/settings) to let you install debug versions of packages *after* a process has crashed.  Then, you reload the backtrace to make it useful.

Comment: @Lukas, yes, you can do that. But sometimes, you have to debug customer sites and dropping in a new executable is not an option, especially for post-mortem stuff.